# PayPal Sandbox subscription webhook response not getting

Tags: paypal-sandbox, webhooks, paypal-subscriptions

I'm trying to get notified via webhooks when a simple payment is made and subscription, however I don't receive any request from paypal on the specified URL. Here is what I've done:

1. I have 2 sandbox accounts: Facilitator and Buyer
2. Create an app (sanbox mode) for the facilitator account
3. Add a webhook URL in that app
4. Login into sanbox.paypal.com with the sandbox facilitator username and password
5. Get payment through express checkout and customer also agree for subscription
6. Received success response from PayPal
7. Prepare query string to create subscription for that customer and send data through REST Api
8. Received response from PayPal related to subscription.

When I login to business account or Facilitator account, I can see bot payment and subscription transaction but the webhook page on my server is not called.

Also if I go to Developer Account -> Webhook Notifications and select the app I have this message: You don't have any events for the selected application

**NOTE: If I add the URL in the webhook simulator everything works great.**

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add "All events" for your webhook endpoint.
Then check if you received anything after completing your order in Developer Account -> Webhook Notifications.
If you still get nothing there, consider cross checking your clientId + secret that you use while creating your order.